# .net не могу перейти на клиентское приложение на Angular 7

Tags: .net, asp.net, маршрутизация, angular, spa

Пишу первое приложение на asp.net и не знаю как перейти на angular роутер.
При запуске попадаю на страницу "Home" из .net, вместо Angular.

вот файл настроек проекта LaunchSettings.json:

```html
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:54035",
      "sslPort": 44319
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "RealWorldApp": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000"
    }
  }
}
```

.net приложение запускается на порту "sslPort": 44319

В Startup.cs используются следующие настройки:

```
services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

app.UseWebpackDevMiddleware(new WebpackDevMiddlewareOptions() {
    HotModuleReplacement = true
});

app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

как мне нужно настроить проект, чтобы запускалось SPA и я мог обращаться к web.api .net?

Answer (score -1):

Видимо, ты пытаешься .NET и Angular слепить в одно большое приложение. Не надо так. Angular запускается на отдельном порту (обычно 4200), а .NET на другом (например 8080). И в самом простом случае просто из Angular'a делаешь запросы на localhost:8080.

Comment: причем тут одно к другому? скомпилированный бандл это обычная статика, которая может сервится даже через nginx

Comment: @overthesanity смешно, что ты ходишь минусишь мои ответы, язвишь в комментах типа умный, а сам ничего предложить не можешь. Интересно так жить, да?